# variable becomes undefined when used inside mongoose findOne in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

while creating an object and then querying it through findOne it is not picked. below is my use case

```
const findOrderByStatus = (orderStatus, userDetails) => {
  let orderById = new Types.ObjectId(userDetails._id);
  console.log({ status: orderStatus, orderedBy: orderById });
  console.log('order status:', orderStatus); // printing orderStatus value which is 'requested'
  return Order.findOne({ status: orderStatus, orderedBy: orderById }); // but here orderStatus value becomes undefined
};
```

status attribute is a **@safer-bwd/mongoose-state-machine**. **orderStatus** is printing outside the Order.findOne, but inside Order.findOne it becomes **undefined** even though a value is hardcoded still the value becomes undefined, but after restarting the server it is able to pick the value.

below is my query **before restarting the server**,

Mongoose: orders.findOne({ status: undefined }, { projection: {} })

below is the query **after restarting the server**,

Mongoose: orders.findOne({ status: 'requested' }, { projection: {} })

I couldn't understand why is it happening.

Answer (score 0):

The bug has been fixed.

https://github.com/safer-bwd/mongoose-state-machine/issues/4

Thanks for the detailed description of the problem.

Comment: Its better to state as to what was the issue how it got solved